# fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Project\pytorch\build\lib\caffe2_protos.lib'

Tags: pytorch, caffe2

I am trying to setup caffe2 without gpu in windows and I am getting the following error:

I have tried installation from caffe2 page but that didn't work. So I have tried the steps from the pytorch's github :
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#binaries

I have ran this from VSCODe by Anaconda.
I have instlled all the dependencies.

I am building from source. I ran build_winows.bat from vscode.

```
[1996/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...hon.dir\csrc\jit\python_interpreter.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[1997/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...torch_python.dir\csrc\jit\python_ir.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[1998/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...iles\torch_python.dir\csrc\jit\init.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2000/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...ython.dir\csrc\multiprocessing\init.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2001/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...hon.dir\csrc\jit\python_arg_flatten.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2002/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...src\jit\script\python_sugared_value.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
..\torch\csrc\jit\script\python_sugared_value.cpp(30): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::script::getRecursiveScriptMode': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/script/python_sugared_value.h(195): note: see previous definition of 'getRecursiveScriptMode'
[2004/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...rch_python.dir\csrc\jit\script\init.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2005/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...keFiles\torch_python.dir\csrc\utils.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2006/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...dir\csrc\utils\throughput_benchmark.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2007/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...es\torch_python.dir\csrc\utils\init.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2008/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...les\torch_python.dir\csrc\onnx\init.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2010/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...torch_python.dir\csrc\serialization.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2012/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...ython.dir\csrc\tensor\python_tensor.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2013/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc..._python.dir\csrc\utils\tensor_apply.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2016/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...on.dir\csrc\utils\python_arg_parser.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2021/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...h_python.dir\csrc\utils\tensor_list.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2023/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc...ch_python.dir\csrc\utils\tensor_new.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2025/2139] Building CXX object caffe2\torc..._python.dir\csrc\utils\tuple_parser.cpp.obj
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(302): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(309): warning C4273: 'torch::jit::tracer::addInputs': inconsistent dll linkage
D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'addInputs'
[2026/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...fe2_detectron_ops.dir\ps_roi_pool_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\ps_roi_pool_op.cc(26): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_PSRoIPool': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\ps_roi_pool_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_PSRoIPool'
..\modules\detectron\ps_roi_pool_op.cc(69): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_PSRoIPoolGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\ps_roi_pool_op.cc(22): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_PSRoIPoolGradient'
[2027/2139] Building CXX object modules\det..._detectron_ops.dir\smooth_l1_loss_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(26): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SmoothL1Loss': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SmoothL1Loss'
..\modules\detectron\smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(76): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SmoothL1LossGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(22): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SmoothL1LossGradient'
[2028/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...ffe2_detectron_ops.dir\roi_pool_f_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\roi_pool_f_op.cc(24): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_RoIPoolF': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\roi_pool_f_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_RoIPoolF'
..\modules\detectron\roi_pool_f_op.cc(62): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_RoIPoolFGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\roi_pool_f_op.cc(22): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_RoIPoolFGradient'
[2029/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...ron_ops.dir\select_smooth_l1_loss_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\select_smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(28): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SelectSmoothL1Loss': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\select_smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SelectSmoothL1Loss'
..\modules\detectron\select_smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(66): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SelectSmoothL1LossGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\select_smooth_l1_loss_op.cc(24): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SelectSmoothL1LossGradient'
[2030/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...ectron_ops.dir\sigmoid_focal_loss_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_focal_loss_op.cc(26): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidFocalLoss': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_focal_loss_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidFocalLoss'
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_focal_loss_op.cc(80): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidFocalLossGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_focal_loss_op.cc(22): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidFocalLossGradient'
[2031/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...ps.dir\sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_op.cc(28): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss'
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_op.cc(63): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidCrossEntropyLossGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_op.cc(24): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SigmoidCrossEntropyLossGradient'
[2032/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...affe2_detectron_ops.dir\sample_as_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\sample_as_op.cc(24): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SampleAs': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\sample_as_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SampleAs'
..\modules\detectron\sample_as_op.cc(47): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SampleAsGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\sample_as_op.cc(22): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SampleAsGradient'
[2033/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...tectron_ops.dir\spatial_narrow_as_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\spatial_narrow_as_op.cc(26): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SpatialNarrowAs': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\spatial_narrow_as_op.cc(21): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SpatialNarrowAs'
..\modules\detectron\spatial_narrow_as_op.cc(48): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SpatialNarrowAsGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\spatial_narrow_as_op.cc(22): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SpatialNarrowAsGradient'
[2034/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...ectron_ops.dir\softmax_focal_loss_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\softmax_focal_loss_op.cc(28): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SoftmaxFocalLoss': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\softmax_focal_loss_op.cc(23): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SoftmaxFocalLoss'
..\modules\detectron\softmax_focal_loss_op.cc(78): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SoftmaxFocalLossGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\softmax_focal_loss_op.cc(24): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_SoftmaxFocalLossGradient'
[2035/2139] Building CXX object modules\mod...test_dynamic.dir\module_test_dynamic.cc.obj
..\modules\module_test\module_test_dynamic.cc(39): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_Caffe2ModuleTestDynamicDummy': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\module_test\module_test_dynamic.cc(37): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_Caffe2ModuleTestDynamicDummy'
[2036/2139] Building CXX object modules\det...etectron_ops.dir\upsample_nearest_op.cc.obj
..\modules\detectron\upsample_nearest_op.cc(35): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_UpsampleNearest': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\upsample_nearest_op.cc(30): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_UpsampleNearest'
..\modules\detectron\upsample_nearest_op.cc(54): warning C4273: 'caffe2::CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_UpsampleNearestGradient': inconsistent dll linkage
..\modules\detectron\upsample_nearest_op.cc(31): note: see previous definition of 'CAFFE2_PLEASE_ADD_OPERATOR_SCHEMA_FOR_UpsampleNearestGradient'
[2037/2139] Linking CXX shared library bin\torch.dll
FAILED: bin/torch.dll lib/torch.lib
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Anaconda\Library\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_dll --intdir=caffe2\CMakeFiles\torch.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100177~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100177~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1421~1.277\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\torch.rsp  /out:bin\torch.dll /implib:lib\torch.lib /pdb:bin\torch.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /INCREMENTAL:NO   && cd
."
LINK: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1421~1.277\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\torch.rsp /out:bin\torch.dll /implib:lib\torch.lib /pdb:bin\torch.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:bin\torch.dll.manifest" failed (exit code 1181) with the following output:
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Project\pytorch\build\lib\caffe2_protos.lib'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 753, in <module>
    build_deps()
  File "setup.py", line 327, in build_deps
    cmake=cmake)
  File "D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\tools\build_pytorch_libs.py", line 64, in build_caffe2
    cmake.build(my_env)
  File "D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\tools\setup_helpers\cmake.py", line 354, in build
    self.run(build_args, my_env)
  File "D:\Caffe2 Project\pytorch\tools\setup_helpers\cmake.py", line 110, in run
    check_call(command, cwd=self.build_dir, env=env)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 341, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', 'install', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j', '4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```